# Swift's definition of Type Annotation

Tags: swift, type-annotation

In Swift Programming Language guide, it has this definition for Type Annotation: "A type annotation explicitly specifies the type of a **variable** or **expression**."

We all know how to specify the type of a **variable**, but how exactly do you specify the type of an **expression**?

Comment: `let someNumber = 10` is implicitly determined to be an `Int` by the compiler, but you can specificly a different (or same) type explicitly such as in `let someNumber : Double = 10`

Comment: I am asking how to specify the type of an expression, not variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple documentation says: "in

```
let someTuple: (Double, Double) = (2.14159, 2.71828)
```

the **expression** `someTuple` is specified to have the tuple type..." (emphasis mine).  Thus a `let` or `var` binding is an example using a type annotation on an **expression**.

A type annotation for a **variable** is illustrated as specifying the type for a function parameter:

```
func someFunction(a:Int) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: This is called variable declaration, not expression.  Expression should return a value or cause a side effect or both - variable declaration does not fulfill this definition.

Comment: I tend to agree with you but I was quoting the Apple documentation.

Comment: The perspective is that the type of (3.14, 2....), an expression, is being specified.

Comment: You are right - the right side is a parenthesized expression.  Answer selected.

Answer (score 0):

You use a colon to tell the compiler what type your expression or variable has.

e.g.

`let year : Int = 2005
 let isRaining : Bool = true`

The `: Int` part **is** the type annotation here.

Comment: I know what a type annotation is. Your declaration is variable declaration, not expression.  I would like to know how to use type annotation on an expression, like the guide suggests.

Comment: I think you're looking too much into it.. But - following on from your quote from the Swift Programming Language guide, there's the following quote: `let someTuple: (Double, Double) = (3.14159, 2.71828)` " In the first example, the **expression** someTuple is specified to have the tuple type (Double, Double). "